# Find the longest even sum in array

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I'm trying to solve a question which takes an array of size n, and find the longest range of numbers in the array which have an even sum.

For example, for the array: [2,3,1,8,4,7,2] the value 5 will be returned, as the range of the first five numbers are the longest range to make an even sum.

I got an algorithm that works, but it's the bonus I'm looking to go into.
The request is to only read from the array's value once and only once.

My solution included summing up the entire array, and then from start to finish find the maximum length, and then from finish to start.
But that's reading the array 3 times.

Can you maybe guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You want me to write it for you or just explain how to do it?

Comment: I would love an explanation, sort of pseudo code. I've been thinking of finding the first  uneven number in the array, saving it's index and counting the rest of the uneven numbers. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: @EatayMizrachi that's what I would do. Either the total sum is even, or you need to drop one uneven number. So indeed looping once over the array, and keep the index of the first uneven number. But also keep the index of the last uneven number. If the last uneven number is closer to the end, drop that number and all even numbers after that.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I would just like you to know that when I said bonus, it was easy to misinterpret what I was doing.  This assignment is not graded, it's a bonus as it's a greater challenge to find an answer to that. If you'll note, I also added a comment, asking if I'm in the right direction.

Comment: @iota Very much so, thank you for the thorough explanation. :)

Comment: @Eatay Mizrachi No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of two odd numbers is even and the sum of two even numbers is even, so a subarray has an even sum if and only if there are an even number of odd numbers. Thus, we can find the answer by keeping track of the index of the first odd number, the index of the last odd number, and the number of odd numbers. If there are an even number of odd numbers, the entire array's sum is even. Otherwise, we can get maximum length of the subarray from the index of the first odd number plus one to the end of the array and the subarray from the front of the array to one less than the last index of an odd number. These subarrays are both the largest possible with an even number of odd numbers, since one odd number is excluded from each one.

```js
function longestEven(arr) {
  let firstOdd = -1,
    lastOdd = -1,
    oddCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 === 1) {
      if (firstOdd === -1) firstOdd = i;
      lastOdd = i;
      ++oddCount;
    }
  }
  return oddCount % 2 === 0 ? arr.length : 
    Math.max(arr.length - (firstOdd + 1), lastOdd);
}
console.log(longestEven([2, 3, 1, 8, 4, 7, 2]));
```